# Calculating completion time of scheduled dependent tasks

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to calculate least completion time of a project schedule, which has n number of tasks and each task can have a dependency task.

### example

```
Task ID    Duration Days    Dependent ID
1          10               0
2          3                0
3          6                1
4          5                2
5          10               1
```

Task with no dependency is mentioned 0 as Dependent ID

from the above task table, the project duration should be calculated as 20 days.

any algorithm should be used to calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume task 0 finishes at day 0.

Add a new column to your table, "completion day".

Go down the list of tasks, add the duration of the current task onto the completion day of the task it is dependent on. Store that as the current task's completion day.

Find the max completion day.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using a technique called a PERT chart, which is just a directed graph in which nodes represent "events" which are the completions of "activities" or groups of activities. You need a start event and an end event, and your other events in your example will be completion of each task. The edges of the graph are arrows representing tasks which go from prerequisite event to result, with weights equal to time to complete task. So you'll have an arrow from start to 1 of weight 10, from start to 2 of weight 3, from 1 to 3 of weight 6, 1 to 5 of weight 10, from 2 to 4 of weight 5, and from 3, 4, 5 to End of weight 0.

Then you work your way from start to end, filling in the time to reach each event node. Time to reach start is 0, to reach 1 is 10, to reach 2 is 3, to reach 3 is 16 (add time to reach 1 to weight 6), time to reach 4 is 3+5 =8, time to reach 5 is 10+10=20, and time to reach End is max (16+0,8+0,20+0) =20. Filling in the time to reach nodes of the graph is a dynamic programming application. The nodes can be filled in the order given by topologically sorting the graph.